# Move pictures to albums and shared albums in iOS 13

Tags: ios, photos

I used to be able to select pictures, hit share and then be able to put them in personal or shared albums using the iOS Photos app. Now in iOS 13, I can’t see the Photos link anymore.

How can I do this in iOS 13? I know I can go to the album and hit +, but this workflow is reversed and I would have to find my photos again.

Comment: I can follow the steps you outline and do without a problem.  I can select a picture (from within Photos), select the Share button, choose "Add to Shared Album" and it goes there.  Can you be more specific about what steps you're taking?  Adding screenshots will help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now see the ”Edit actions” link. Don’t know if that came with the 13.1.2 update or if I just missed it before. But from there I can add the missing actions. I don’t know why they went away after the update but I now added them back and everything works as expected.